# Escritura, lectura, busqueda y modificacion de archivo de texto, clases c++

Tags: c++, poo, archivo, clase

He estado un poco trabado en esto, de manejo de archivo o sincronía de archivo con el programa, necesito que me echen una mano y me ilustren sobre esto.

En la clase usuarios como verán escribo en un fichero de texto ("*usuarios.txt*")

Lo que busco con todo esto es, poder buscar en el archivo (para que no solo sea de escritura) modificar y mostrar los datos de los usuarios individuales, es decir que se guarde todo los datos ingresados y al momento de ejecutarlo nuevamente estén los datos.

El siguiente código es en lo que he estado trabajando, lo coloco para entiendan mejor mi pregunta.

**CLASE PERSONA: (clase padre)**

*Cabecera*

```
#ifndef PERSO_H
#define PERSO_H
#include <iostream>   
#include <string>

using namespace std;
// Atributos
class perso {
private:
    string nombre, apellido, telefono; 
public:
    string cedula;
    void regis_perso (string nom, string ape, string ced, string tel); //Registra los datos de la clase.
};
#endif /* PERSO_H */
```

**CPP**

```
#include "perso.h"

using namespace std;

void perso::regis_perso(string nom, string ape, string ced, string tel)
{
    nombre = nom;
    apellido = ape;
    cedula = ced;
    telefono = tel;
}
```

**CLASE USUARIO (clase heredada)**

*Cabecera*

```
#ifndef USER_H
#define USER_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "perso.h"

using namespace std;
//Atributos
class user: public perso{
public:
    string iduser;
    void regis_user (string nom, string ape, string ced, string tel, string idu, string fec, string pas, string sex); //Registra los datos de la clase.
private:
    string fechana, pass, sexo;
};

#endif /* USER_H */
```

**CPP**

```
#include "user.h"

void user::regis_user (string nom, string ape, string ced, string tel, string idu, string fec, string pas, string sex)
{
    regis_perso (nom, ced, ape, tel);
    iduser = idu;
    fechana = fec;
    pass = pas;
    sexo = sex;   
}
```

**CLASE USUARIOS**

*Cabecera*

```
//Clase arreglo de objeto (de user).
#ifndef USERS_H
#define USERS_H
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "user.h"
#include "modulos.h"
//Atributos de la clase.
using namespace std;

class users {
public:
    bool exis_user (string ced, string idu); //Función que verifica si existe un usuario (verdadero si falso no). 
    int pos_vacia_users (); //Función que devuelve la posición vació del arreglo "usuarios".
    int pos_user (string ced, string idu); //Función que devuelve la posición del "usuario".
    void insta_users (); //Inicializa cada posición del arreglo "usuarios".
    void regis_users (); //Modulo que registra los datos de los usuario.
    user usuarios [10];
};

#endif /* USERS_H */
```

**CPP**

```
#include "users.h"

bool users::exis_user (string ced, string idu)
{
    bool enc;
    enc = false;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        if ((usuarios[i].cedula == ced) and (usuarios[i].iduser == idu))
        {
            enc = true;
        }
    }
    return (enc);
}
void users::insta_users ()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        usuarios[i].inici_user ();
    }
}
int users::pos_vacia_users ()
{
    int pos, i;
    i = 0;
    pos = 2016;
    while ((pos == 2016) and (i <= 9))
    {
        if ((usuarios[i].cedula == "VACIO") and (usuarios[i].iduser == "VACIO"))
        {
            pos = i;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return (pos);
}
int users::pos_user (string ced, string idu)
{
    int pos, i;
    i = 0;
    pos = 2016;
    while ((pos == 2016) and (i <= 9))
    {
        if ((usuarios[i].cedula == ced) and (usuarios[i].iduser == idu))
        {
            pos = i;
        }
        i = i + 1;
    }
    return (pos);
}
void users::regis_users ()
{
    string nombre, apellido, cedula, telefono, fechana, pass, sexo, iduser;
    ofstream escriuser;
    escriuser.open ("usuarios.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
    bool aux;
    int pos, resp;
    resp = 0;
    aux = false;
    resp = 0;
    if (escriuser.is_open())
    {
        while (resp == 0)
        {
            nombre = "";
            apellido = "";
            cedula = "";
            telefono = "";
            fechana = "";
            pass = "";
            sexo = "";
            iduser = "";
            pos = 0;
            pos = pos_vacia_users ();
            if (pos == 2016)
            {
                cout << "No se pueden registrar mas usuarios (registro lleno)." << endl;
                press_key ();
                resp = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                cout << "REGISTRO DE USUARIO NRO: " <<pos<< endl;
                cout << "Introduzca los siguientes datos:" << endl;
                cout << "Cedula:" << endl; //Se pueden verificar los datos independientemente
                cin >> cedula;
                cout << "Nombre de usuario (ID user):" << endl;
                cin >> iduser;
                aux = exis_user(cedula, iduser);
                while (aux == true) 
                {
                    cedula = "";
                    iduser = "";
                    cout << "Error!!! Los datos introducidos pertenecen a un usuario ya existente." << endl;
                    press_key ();
                    cout << "Intentelo nuevamente..." << endl;
                    cout << "Cedula:" << endl;
                    cin >> cedula;
                    cout << "Nombre de usuario:" << endl;
                    cin >> iduser;
                    aux = exis_user(cedula, iduser);
                }
                cout << "Nombre:" << endl;
                cin >> nombre;
                cout << "Apellido:" << endl;
                cin >> apellido;
                cout << "Telefono:" << endl;
                cin >> telefono;
                cout << "Fecha de nacimiento:" << endl;
                cin >> fechana;
                cout << "Contrase;a:" << endl;
                cin >> pass;
                cout << "Sexo:" << endl;
                cin >> sexo;
                usuarios[pos].regis_user(nombre, apellido, cedula, telefono, iduser, fechana, pass, sexo);
                escriuser<<nombre<<" "<<apellido<<" "<<cedula<<" "<<telefono<<" "<<iduser<<" "<<fechana<<" "<<pass<<" "<<sexo<<endl;
                cout << "¿Desea registrar otro usuario?" << endl;
                cout << "(0./ SI, 1./NO)" << endl;
                cin >> resp;
                while ((resp != 1) and (resp != 2))
                {
                    cout << "Error!!! Respuesta invalida." << endl;
                    press_key ();
                    cout << "Intentelo nuevamente." << endl;
                    cin >> resp;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error!!! el archivo no pudo ser abierto." << endl;
    }
    escriuser.close ();
}
```

---

Seria genial que en sus respuestas me dieran recomendaciones, ejemplos o sugerencias, para así ayudarme en esto.

Comment: Si ya tienes el arreglo `usuarios` lo que podrías que hacer es volcar el contenido del fichero en dicho arreglo y buscar sobre el mismo. No tiene demasiado sentido que tanto el fichero como el arreglo estén sincronizados y que intentes hacer búsquedas sobre el fichero.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu sugerencia, la tomare en cuenta. :D

Comment: Tal sugerencia haría que surja otra pregunta, como asignar los valores del archivo al arreglo de usuarios?

Comment: Una forma de hacerlo es con un bucle: se crea un objeto `user`, se rellena con la información del registro que toque del fichero y se copia en la posición que le coresponda. Para hacer esto tendrías que abrir el fichero en modo lectura. ¿Cuándo realizar esta lectura? Supongo que al arrancar el programa.

Comment: Nuevamente gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Puedo agregar aunque talvez es muy claro que al finalizar el programa sobrescribes el arreglo dentro del fichero para que se guarden los cambio